# Why is this "Constructor" called with parameters in Python?

Tags: python

Please don't close this question if you don't really understand what's happening in this code. This is different than ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

In the following code, I defined a `clone` method where it calls the "constructor" without parameters. But within the `__init__` method, the value of the parameter keeps changing (see the `WARNING` lines of the output). Why is that?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, aDic = {}):
        self.aDic = aDic
        print("__init__")
        if aDic:
            print("WARNING: aDic is not empty {}".format(aDic))
        self.printme()

    def printme(self):
        print("aDic = {}".format(self.aDic))

    def clone(self, props):
        print("Before calling Foo() without parameters")
        newValue = Foo()
        print("after calling Foo() without parameters")
        newValue.printme()
        print("props = {}".format(props))
        print("props.get = {}".format(props.get("aDic", self.aDic)))
        for k, v in props.get("aDic", self.aDic).items():
            newValue.aDic[k] = v
        return newValue


a = Foo(aDic = {"b": 2})
a.printme()
print()

c = a.clone({"aDic": {"b": 222}})
c.printme()
print()

a.printme()
print()

d = a.clone({"aDic": {"b": 2222}})
d.printme()
print()
```

Output:

```
__init__
WARNING: aDic is not empty {'b': 2}
aDic = {'b': 2}
aDic = {'b': 2}

Before calling Foo() without parameters
__init__
aDic = {}
after calling Foo() without parameters
aDic = {}
props = {'aDic': {'b': 222}}
props.get = {'b': 222}
aDic = {'b': 222}

aDic = {'b': 2}

Before calling Foo() without parameters
__init__
WARNING: aDic is not empty {'b': 222}
aDic = {'b': 222}
after calling Foo() without parameters
aDic = {'b': 222}
props = {'aDic': {'b': 2222}}
props.get = {'b': 2222}
aDic = {'b': 2222}
```

Comment: Actually this is the same problem that happens in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument. The default argument `aDict` is a mutable object and therefore if one call modifies it the next time you want the default value for `aDict` you will get the modified one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

In `clone()`, you call `Foo()` without arguments, so `newValue.aDic` will be the shared dict from the argument list.

You then internally mutate that shared copy (`newValue.aDic[k] = v`), so all  `Foo()`s you get form the `clone()` function will see those changes.

A modified version of your example illustrates this. See how the `id`s  are the same?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, aDic = {}):
        self.aDic = aDic

    def printme(self):
        print(f"aDic({id(self.aDic)}) = {self.aDic}")

    def clone(self, props):
        newValue = Foo()
        newValue.printme()
        for k, v in props.get("aDic", self.aDic).items():
            newValue.aDic[k] = v
        return newValue


print("a")
a = Foo(aDic = {"b": 2})
a.printme()
print("c")
c = a.clone({"aDic": {"b": 222}})
c.printme()
print("d")
d = a.clone({"aDic": {"b": 2222}})
d.printme()
```

prints out (e.g.)

```
a
aDic(4494684352) = {'b': 2}
c
aDic(4494684544) = {}
aDic(4494684544) = {'b': 222}
d
aDic(4494684544) = {'b': 222}
aDic(4494684544) = {'b': 2222}
```